# How to specify `scale_color_manual()` in `python`, using `lets-plot`

Tags: python, ggplot2, lets-plot

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from lets_plot import *
LetsPlot.setup_html()

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-docs/master/data/mpg2.csv')

ggplot(data, aes(x="engine horsepower", y="miles per gallon")) + geom_point(aes(color="origin of car"))
```

And the output is:
[image]

In `R`, using `ggplot2`, I would manually set the colors by writing:

```
... + scale_color_manual(values = c("US" = "red", "Asia" = "green", "Europe" = "blue")
```

How can I do the same in `Python` with `lets-plot`?

`lets-plot` reference manual for this function doesn't seem to help: [here](https://lets-plot.org/pages/api/lets_plot.scale_color_manual.html?highlight=scale_color_manual#lets_plot.scale_color_manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's the same in `lets-plot`. Using a pandas Series you could create a named vector similar to R:

```
import pandas as pd
from lets_plot import *
LetsPlot.setup_html()

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-docs/master/data/mpg2.csv')

ggplot(data, aes(x="engine horsepower", y="miles per gallon")) + \
    geom_point(aes(color="origin of car")) + \
    scale_color_manual(values = pd.Series(["red", "green", "blue"], 
                                          index=['US', 'Asia', 'Europe']))
```

[image]